# jQuery: highlight even columns (not rows)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

How to colorize even (or odd) table columns using jQuery?
(without adding classes manually)

My markup is:

```
<table>
   <caption>Table caption</caption>
   <thead>
   <tr><th scope="col">Table header 1</th><th scope="col">Table header 2</th><th scope="col">Table header 3</th><th scope="col">Table header 3</th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>

        <tr><th scope="row">Table row header</th><td>Table data</td><td>Table data</td><td>Table data</td></tr>
        <tr><th scope="row">Table row header</th><td>Table data</td><td>Table data</td><td>Table data</td></tr>
        <tr><th scope="row">Table row header</th><td>Table data</td><td>Table data</td><td>Table data</td></tr>

        <tr><th scope="row">Table row header</th><td>Table data</td><td>Table data</td><td>Table data</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

(it may or may not contain scope attribs or `th` tags)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`:nth-child()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) for this:

```
$('table tr :nth-child(2n)').css('background-color', '#eee');
```

[You can see a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/mYuHR/), this version does the columns, regardless if the cell is a `<th>` or `<td>` you can add that in there (e.g. `td:nth-child(2n)`) if you want to do only one or the other.  If you want to select the *other* columns, just do `2n+1` instead.
​

Comment: +1: Thanks for your comment in my answer and providing the right solution here.

Comment: Thanks, this one works fine (previous version did some kind of checkers ;)

Comment: Is this possible without JS? CSS3 only?

Comment: Worth noting here that I don't think this will work if you have anything rowspanned in your table since the second child will no longer be the second column.

Comment: Thanks for the link to [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) too, I didn't know this tool.

Comment: @Chris, yes, for simplest markup from my question this is OK. Any solution for rowspanned tables?

Comment: @Nick, This is really nice. Wondering which up-to-date browsers supports this syntax already.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Updated to fix my misreading of the question.

This should work:

```
$('tr > :nth-child(even)').css('background-color','#eee');
```

or

```
$('tr > :nth-child(odd)').css('background-color','#eee');
```

Comment: Ken - OP is coloring columns, not rows. :o)

Comment: This one is coloring rows, I need *columns*

Comment: Ken - You're neglecting the `th` elements that the OP said may or may not be present. :o)